# Superinvestors are long or short on their positions

Tags: united-states, stocks, shorting-securities, long-term

When I am watching [Dataroma](https://www.dataroma.com/) or [TIKR](https://app.tikr.com/), how can I say if a stock held by a superinvestor is short or long? It says how many shares they owned but not if it is short or long.

Comment: Information based on SEC Form 13F filings are long positions, since Form 13F only reports long positions.

Comment: @Flux Thanks! I did not know about that. Is there a way to know their short positions? For instance, I know Michael Burry shorts a lot normally, but I can't say what he is shorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataroma appears to source its data exclusively from US SEC Form 13F filings. Form 13F reports long positions only. In the USA, there is currently no requirement for institutional investment managers to report short positions to the public. According to the [Form 13F FAQ](https://www.sec.gov/divisions/investment/13ffaq):

> **Q: What about short positions?**
>
> **A:** You should not include short positions on Form 13F. You also should not subtract your short position(s) in a security from your long position(s) in that same security; report only the long position.

In February 2022, the SEC proposed to add short sale disclosure rules, so this may change in the future. References: [SEC Proposes Short Sale Disclosure Rule, Order Marking Requirement, and CAT Amendments](https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2022-32), [Statement on Rules to Increase Transparency of Short Sale Activity](https://www.sec.gov/news/statement/gensler-statement-rules-increase-transparency-short-sale-activity-022522).

You may generally assume that the reported positions are long positions, not short positions, unless stated otherwise.